# Update a layout after an orientation change in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Good day,

I'm working on an application that will serve as a monitor of some sort for drivers. My client would like the application to work regardless of the orientation of the device.

I implemented the solution provided [in the following article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) , and after fiddling a bit with the debugger, I can see that the Asynctask is still working. However, the TextViews and ImageViews it is supposed to work on are not working anymore.

Here is the code of my [TaskFragment](http://pastebin.com/zBUbtcpT).

To clarify : The AsyncTask still receive and handle the elements correctly, but the elements of the layout are not updated anymore. I would like to know how I can keep them working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a (probably not very efficient) workaround, but a workaround nonetheless.

The problem was that, after an orientation change, since the Activity is destroyed and recreated, the variables batterymonitor, valuemonitor, etc, would not point towards the new objects created because of the layout/activity change.

As a solution, I am now using a findViewById each time I need to do an operation on the layout. This way, the id is permanently refreshed to keep up with the activity changes on a rotation of the device.

The ugly line I use to do so is :

```
batteryMonitor = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.batteryMonitor);                              
batteryMonitor.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_battery);
```

Comment: Not a bad solution at all. It might not be efficient but it's certainly much easier to implement than a loader. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an AsyncTaskLoader as those can re-attach to whatever lifecycle element you created it in relatively easily. See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

It might seem pretty involved to implement at first, however if you read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html, most of the weirdness should be cleared up.

TLDR: Using AsyncTaskLoader allows an easy way for your AsyncTask to be reattached to your fragment after it is destroyed and recreated. You just need to call getLoaderManager().initLoader(...) in the onCreate of your fragment.

Comment: As I needed a working application pretty quickly, I found a workaround I listed as a good solution.
However, your links on Loaders were very interesting, and if I have to work on a case needing an AsyncTask in the future, I'll probably delve in a little deeper and try to implement it with loaders.

Comment: Glad to hear it, let me know how it goes if you remember to!

Comment: No problem, if I dabble again in Android development and networking I'll be sure to let you know ! Thanks for the info !